# Spring Data Neo4j - @Autowired Repository == null

Tags: spring, neo4j, annotations, autowired, spring-data-neo4j

I try to write a webapp using Spring Data Neo4j.

I have an Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<Neo4jUser> {}
```

an applicationcontext.xml:

```
...
<context:component-scan base-package="de.wilke.test.neo4j" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" 
          expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<!-- REST Connection to Neo4j server --> 
<bean id="restGraphDatabase" 
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" />
</bean>

<bean id="myservice" class="de.wilke.test.neo4j.Neo4jResource">
</bean>

<!-- Neo4j configuration (template) -->
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="restGraphDatabase" />

<!-- Package w/ automagic repositories -->
<neo4j:repositories base-package="de.wilke.test.repository" />
```

And my Neo4jResource:

```
@Controller
public class Neo4jResource {

    @Autowired
    public static UserRepository repo;
    ...
```

Now cannot use the UserRepository in the Controller because it is null...

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` doesn't work for `static` fields.

Also it's not a good idea from design point of view to make this field `static`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that I can think of:

1. Your `<neo4j:repositories base-package=".."/> is not correct`
2. You are not loading your `applicationContext` correctly and the `repo` does not get instantiated properly

Check your package first. Also, do you have anything like the following in your main application?

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

Neo4jResource myBean = context.getBean(Neo4jResource.class);
myBean.functionThatUsesTheRepo();
```

Hope that this helps...