# Mongo custom repository autowired is null

Tags: mongodb, repository, spring-data

I try to autowire my custom mongo repository (and it seems the constructor is executed) but still the result is null

I've looked at some similar questions 
[Spring Data Neo4j - @Autowired Repository == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665670/spring-data-neo4j-autowired-repository-null)
and 
[spring data mongo repository is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071301/spring-data-mongo-repository-is-null)

but I still don't know how to solve this.

```
public class TestRepo {

@Autowired 
PersonRepository repository;

public void find(String name)
   {
        System.out.println(repository.findByName(name));
   }

}
```

config

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.yyyy.zzz" />
```

PersonRepository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, BigInteger> {

@Query("{name : ?0}")
public Person findByName(String name);
}
```

Implementation

```
public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepository{

PersonRepositoryImpl()
{
   System.out.println("constructing");
}

public Person findByName(String name) {
    ...
}

}
```

if I get the repository bean directly from context it works

Answer (score 1):

Your repository setup looks suspicious. To execute query methods, you don't need to provide an implementation at all. I suspect in your current setup the custom implementation you have in `PersonRepositoryImpl` "overrides" the query method and thus will be preferred on execution.

If you simply drop your implementation class, Spring Data will automatically execute the query for you on invocation.

Generally speaking, custom implementation classes are only needed for functionality you cannot get through other means (query methods, Querydsl intergration etc.).

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem, my repository is still null, whether I use the custom impl or the generated one. When using the custom impl I get the output "constructing" , so I don't understand why the repository is null, if an instance of it is surely generated

Comment: Any chance you create a tiny sample project on GitHub or the like? Feels like you're getting lost in details. I'd recommend to start without the custom implementation first and get that to work. For the current setup shown in your post, you don't actually need it at all. It seems to only create confusion, that's why I recommend to remove it from the setup to begin with.